# Java Conversion table convert É to E

Tags: java, escaping, special-characters

Is there a java function/sample of code that will help me convert some unicode characters to its readable counterpart?

For example:

<kbd>Original</kbd> <kbd>converted</kbd>
<kbd>¿</kbd>          <kbd>?</kbd>              
<kbd>À</kbd>          <kbd>A</kbd>              
<kbd>Á</kbd>          <kbd>A</kbd>              
<kbd>À</kbd>          <kbd>A</kbd>              
<kbd>Ã</kbd>          <kbd>A</kbd>              
<kbd>Ä</kbd>          <kbd>A</kbd>              
<kbd>Å</kbd>          <kbd>A</kbd>              
<kbd>Æ</kbd>         <kbd>A</kbd>              
<kbd>Ç</kbd>          <kbd>C</kbd>              
<kbd>Ø</kbd>         <kbd>O</kbd>              
<kbd>Ñ</kbd>         <kbd>N</kbd>              
<kbd>×</kbd>           <kbd>.</kbd>              
<kbd>Î</kbd>            <kbd>I</kbd>              
<kbd>Ï</kbd>          <kbd>I</kbd>                
<kbd>Ð</kbd>         <kbd>D</kbd>              
<kbd>Ñ</kbd>          <kbd>N</kbd>

Or how would you do it?

Comment: I just want to point out that those "Original" Unicode characters are actually readable characters (Maybe not in english, though).

Comment: What do you mean about "design pattern"? If you want to save them, you may use data structure like Map or a class with original and converted attributes.

Comment: I think it is realy up to you to decide what is "readable counterpart" and that is not what a function can do.

Comment: Create a HashTable to map your translations, use it pick the desired output character for a given input character.

Comment: maybe it was not the best choice of words, what I would like to achive is the most efficient way  to convert a large amount charatcters to others... lets say a dictionary of 1000 letters

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) class, but it won't do the whole work for you (it'll do a lot though, so you can handle the corner cases separately). Accents and other diacritical marks can be removed with the following (decomposes characters into the base char and the diacritic, then removes the diacritic marks).

```
String foo = Normalizer.normalize("¿ÀÁÀÃÄÅÆÇØÑ×ÎÏÐÑ", Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
```

After that you still need to handle the characters that weren't converted (`¿ÆØ×Ð`).

Code snippet borrowed from [here](http://drillio.com/en/software/java/remove-accent-diacritic/).